# Django CreateView within Navbar

Tags: html, django

I have a **base_page.html** which includes **navbar** (utilizing {% include %} tag). The idea is to place trigger (**a** tag in my case) within navbar which calls a **CreateView** globally (where the navbar displays) around a project.
So far I managed to place an **a** tag which triggers **CreateView** displays a modal window with form. But problem is a View renders designed to render a single page that makes hard to use that **CreateView** within a project globally.
Wondering if there is a way to use **CreateView** within a navbar everywhere it displays.

```
{% load static %}
```

```
<div class="logo_pic"><a href=""><img src={% static "img/navbar_icons/temp_logo.svg" %} alt="logo_pic"></a></div>

<div class="nav_menu">
    <div class="nav_menu_top">
        <a href=""><img src={% static "img/navbar_icons/home_icon.svg" %} alt="home-button-icon"></a>
        <a href=""><img src={% static "img/navbar_icons/transaction_icon.svg" %} alt="transaction-icon-button"></a>
    </div>

    <div class="nav_menu_bottom">
        <a id="openModalBtn"><img src={% static "img/navbar_icons/add_new_transaction_icon.svg" %} alt="new_transaction"></a>
    </div>

    <!-- Modal window -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal">
        <div class="modal-content">
        <span class="close" id="closeModalBtn">&times;</span>
        <h2>Create new transaction</h2>
            <form method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form }}
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

UPDATE 1:
I've managed to create a **context processor** so form renders on every page contains navbar. How to catch that POST data passed from that particular form? Is there a way to do it in a single view instead of creation Post view for every app?